# How to change repository

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I'm new on Maven, and I'm trying to start a new Springboot project.

I had started on https://start.spring.io and generate a new maven project with web and mongo dependencies.

When I import the project on eclipse, i get the following error:

Project build error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.8.RELEASE from/to Artifactory local-repos (http://mycompanyurl.com/anotherpath): mycompanyurl.com and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM pom.xml /demo   line 5  Maven pom Loading Problem

I have a parent pom (settings.xml) with the following configuration:

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>ArtifactoryCentral</id>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
        <name>develpment Artifactory</name>
        <url>http://mycompanyurl.com/foo</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>defaultId</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
              <id>Artifactory local repo</id>
              <url>http://mycompanyurl.com/anotherpath</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I've tryed to change directly the url tag's value with the url of the maven central repository (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) but isn't working. The error is the same

Comment: Is the parant-subproject pom situation configured properly?

Comment: Do you mean the pom of the project? It's generated by springinitializr. So I suppose that it's configured properly.